# Script Working on Powershell console but not on Powershell ISE

Tags: powershell

This is error message i get when running code with Powershell ISE:

> Exception calling "Substring" with "1" argument(s): "StartIndex cannot
>   be less than zero.
>
> Parameter name: startIndex"
>
> At C:\Users\3N16M4\Desktop\Untitled3.ps1:8 char:1
>
> - $Last=$Role.Substring($Role.IndexOf('FE'))
> - ```
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException
>   ```

```
            $text ="`n"


            $String= Read-Host -Prompt 'Please Enter Value '


            $Role=Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\3N16M4\Desktop\New folder\*.txt' -Recurse |Select-string -Pattern $String -SimpleMatch -Context 9,0 |  Out-String -Stream |Select-Object -Index 1
            $Last=$Role.Substring($Role.IndexOf('FE'))

            $text

            Write-host ('The Answer is: {0}' -f $Last)

            $text

            Read-Host -Prompt 'Press Enter to exit'
```

However running this same code with VScode and powershell console gives no errors and runs just fine , so i was wondering what could be causing that.

Comment: Tried your code and it works for me in ISE. Try closing your ISE and relaunch and try it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$role = "you are the winner of a all expense paid trip to the beautiful beaches of Cancun.  There are few exceptions that a such as this script must be completed before you read all of the details.  The developer that is assisting in the writing of this script will require a new question if you more help.  It was a joy and pleasure to see this issue resolved." ;

Write-host "This String is $(($Role).length) characters long.";

$MaxDisplayWidth = 120;
$role -split '(\w{$MaxDisplayWidth})' | Where-Object {$_};
```

Answer (score 0):

First, do a proper check for your variables because:

```
$Role.IndexOf('FE')
```

Will return `-1` when it cannot find the text `'FE'` in `$Role`.

When it returns `-1` the next statement:

```
$Role.Substring(-1)
```

Will fail with the above error.

This means that the issue lies in how `$Role` is filled. Output `$Role` to see if it is returning what you are expecting. Maybe `$String` is being set differently?

Comment: yea that was it , so it seem based on my powershell windows size code will work or not i don't want that to be a factor

Answer (score 0):

Post the output.

```
$text ="`n"
$String= Read-Host -Prompt 'Please Enter Value '

$Foundfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\temp\*.txt' -Recurse
If ($Foundfiles) {
Write-host "Files have been found. The problem is not here" -ForegroundColor green}
Else { Write-host "Error No files Found" -ForegroundColor Red }


$FilesThatContaintheString = $Foundfiles | Select-string -Pattern $String -SimpleMatch -Context 9,0
If ($FilesThatContaintheString) {Write-host "Found value in a file" -ForegroundColor Green}
Else { write-host  "Did not find the string in any of the files."  -ForegroundColor red}

$convertingToStrings = $FilesThatContaintheString | Out-String -Stream
If ($convertingToStrings) {write-host "Out-string works" -ForegroundColor Green}
Else {Write-host "Out-string is not working" -ForegroundColor red }


$selectTheSecoundOutputedString = $convertingToStrings |Select-Object -Index 1
If ($selectTheSecoundOutputedString) {
Write-host "If you see this then the issue is somewhere else" -ForegroundColor Yellow}
Else {Write-host 'Did not find a second string try $index 0' -ForegroundColor Red}

$Role = $selectTheSecoundOutputedString

Write-host "The value of Role is $role"
Write-host "The Index of FE is $($Role.IndexOf('FE'))"

$Last=$Role.Substring($Role.IndexOf('FE'))
$text
Write-host ('The Answer is: {0}' -f $Last)
$text
Read-Host -Prompt 'Press Enter to exit'
```

Comment: Ok so tested that out until i have figured it out , it seems the output page in powershell ISE was too small so output  of lines was large it had to separate it in 2 lines and the value i wanted was in 2nd line so thats why i get index of -1 however when i increased size if powershell ISE window it worked fine , Never thought that would be the issue thank you .

Comment: However i was wondering if there is a way that can be done regardless of powershell windows size.

Comment: Do you want the powershell window buffer bigger so you can scroll to the right or do you want the text to wrap around regardless of the window size?

Comment: i want it to wrap around regardless of windows size as in if the output is like :
"you are the winner of the prize" and windows size is small i will have word prize in second line so when i try to get line index and get word prize i will get it wrong so i don't want any output to be separated on multiple lines.